# Bitwise addition of large numbers in JavaScript causes negative result

Tags: javascript, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm working on an interview question which requires me to add to strings using bitwise operators. My code below works just fine for small numbers (from 0 up to 123456789). However if I try to add 1234567890 + 1234567890, surprisingly I get a negative result. I'm guessing that this is due to Javascript's 32bit limitation.

I tried to split the input numbers by dividing them by 2 for example but it leads to wrong computation. Is there a way to properly split the input numbers and add them later on at the end of the computation?

```
const addStrings = (s1, s2) => {
  let sum = s1 ^ s2
  let carry = (s1 & s2) << 1 

  if (sum & carry) {
    return addStrings(sum, carry)
  } else {
    return (sum ^ carry)
  }

}
```

Comment: How did you split them?

Comment: @harold I couldn't split. That's why I posted this question.

Comment: But you tried to do it, right? Perhaps it was almost correct, needing only some small modification

Comment: Yes I simply divided the input numbers by two to reduce the amount of bits used. Nothing sophisticated

Comment: Ok so you divide by 2 and add the numbers, and then didn't add the least significant bits back in the end? That could be the bug

Comment: Yes, I didn't add the least significant bits. Just multiplied the result by 2 at the end. Thanks for the tip